# Getting a variable from a JSON file and then modifying the file in a Next.js project deployed to Vercel

Tags: next.js, vercel

I'm using a JSON file to mock a database for some testing. I'm calling and modifying this JSON from Next.js API routes.

This is working locally but when I deploy it to Vercel I'm getting a 500 error.

```
const fs = require('fs');

let users = require('data/users.json');

export const usersDBmock = {
  delete: _delete
};


function _delete(id) {
  users = users.filter((x) => x.id !== id);
  saveData();
}


function saveData() {
   fs.writeFileSync('data/users.json', JSON.stringify(users));
}
```

In my `/pages/api` endpoint I'm calling

```
usersDBmock.delete(123);
```

Error I'm getting

```
    "error": {
        "errno": -30,
        "syscall": "open",
        "code": "EROFS",
        "path": "data/users.json"
    }
```

My suspicious is that `'data/users.json'`is not the correct path in Vercel but I can figure out how to do it.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the body of the 500 error?

Comment: @NickMcCurdy     "error": {
        "errno": -30,
        "syscall": "open",
        "code": "EROFS",
        "path": "data/users.json"
    }

Comment: Do you need to persist the saved data too? Vercel has a readonly file system, so you wouldn't be able to do that without a database or CDN anyway.